# How to bind a command to Window Loaded event using WPF and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

There is a button which is binded to a command like this on my WPF window :

```
<Button Command="{Binding SearchCommand}">
```

I want that Command to be executed when that window is loaded.
I added this to xaml :

```
Loaded="DXWindow_Loaded">
```

And I added this to code-behind, but I don't know what to write to fill the method.

```
private void DXWindow_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

How can I call that SearchCommand or SearchExecute from code-behind? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you bind your ViewModel to your View's DataContext.

```
var vm = this.DataContext as YourViewModel;
vm.SearchCommand.Execute(null);
```